# reactjs pagination - not able to render props.item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

Am trying to make a pagination in reactjs application. Please find the code below.

Finally am not able to render the list. Its giving blank list. could someone help me out to figure out the error here.?

Please find the complete code. Added  component from where am rendering the list and pagination component is added in this class only.

Please find the demo data below. Data coming from mongodb as JSON objects.

```
return (
<table className="table table-hover"  style={{
minWidth: 600,
}} >
<thead >
<tr>
<th>Order Number</th>
<th>Customer Name</th>
<th>Created By</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<SearchResultsList items={ this.props.results } open={ this.props.open } />
</table>
);
}
}

class SearchResultsList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { };
}
render() {
const per_page=10;
const pages = Math.ceil(this.props.items.length / per_page);
const current_page = 1;
const start_offset = (current_page - 1) * per_page;
let start_count =0;

  return (
    <tbody>
      {
        this.props.items.sort(
        (a, b) => moment(b.order_date) - moment(a.order_date) || b.order_number - a.order_number)
        .map((item, index) => {
          if (index >= start_offset && start_count < per_page ){
            start_count++;
            <SearchResultsItem key={ item.id } item={ item } open={ this.props.open } />
          }
        })
      }
    </tbody>
  );

  <Pagination 
    className="items-pagination pull-right"
    bsSize="medium"
    maxButton={10}
    first last next prev boundaryLinks
    item={pages}
    activePage={current_page} />
}

class SearchResultsItem extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
this.state = { };
}
handleInputChange(e) {
const target = e.target;
const name = target.name;
const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
this.setState({ [name]: value });
}
render() {

return(  
<tr  style={{fontsize: '10',cursor: 'pointer'}}
<td>{ this.props.item.order_number }</td>
<td>{ this.props.item.customer_name }</td>
<td>{ this.props.item.buyer_name }</td>
</tr>
); 
}
}
```

Please find the demo data :

```
{ 
"_id" : "658ecv57b-3853-46f4-af6c-cb1ca111137f", 
"order_number" : "1000123", 
"customer_name" : "rahul", 
"buyer_name" : "rahul", 
}
{ 
"_id" : "1258ecv57b-3853-46f4-af6c-cb1ca111137f", 
"order_number" : "1000123", 
"customer_name" : "Bruce", 
"buyer_name" : "Bruce", 
}
{ 
"_id" : "658ecv57b-3853-46f4-af6c-cb1ca1111312f", 
"order_number" : "1000123", 
"customer_name" : "mike", 
"buyer_name" : "mike", 
}
{ 
"_id" : "658ecv57b-3853-46f4-af6c-cb112111137f", 
"order_number" : "1000123", 
"customer_name" : "linda", 
"buyer_name" : "linda", 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: did u forget to `return` the `SearchResultItem` inside `map` ?

Comment: And `Pagination` outside `return` ?

Comment: Nope.. am return <searchResultItem>  . Please find the remaining code..                                                                
    class SearchResultsItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.state = { };
    }
    
   render() {
   return(  
   <tr  >
   <td>{ this.props.item.order_number }</td>
    </tr>
    ); 
    }
    }

Comment: then edit the question with that code too... and make it **readable**

Comment: Added complete code now.

Comment: still `Pagination` is outside `return`. Which component does the render function in the beginning belong to ?

Comment: Also if you can post a sample props object (actual data) that you are trying to pass, might be more helpful to debug.

Comment: updated with demo data ( props object ).